# reference paragraphs inside itself

Tags: angularjs, filter, highlight

i'm trying to highlight text in my existing pages. these pages are all neatly built like

```
<p>some text</p>
<p>some more text</p>
```

etc..

now I put an input box where all text inside it would highlight text on the page:

```
<input ng-model='highlightthis'>
```

I built a filter in angular app like this:

```
app.filter('highlight', function($sce) {
  return function(text, phrase) {
   if (phrase) text = text.replace(new RegExp('('+phrase+')', 'gi'),
     '<span class="highlighted">$1</span>')
   return $sce.trustAsHtml(text)
  }
});
```

and a quick style:

```
<style>.highlighted { background: yellow; } </style>
```

now.. I thought all I needed to do was add the filter to all the `<p>`'s in my existing pages. but I can't seem to find the right syntax for it:

```
<p ng-bind-html="$(this).innerHTML | highlight:highlightthis>some text</p>
```

etc..

but it doesn't work. anybody got a clue as to how to link the inner text from the `<p>`'s to the filter? 
also, there's probably some smart way to add the ng-bind to all the `<p>`'s on page load instead of manually adding it to all the p's on the pages.. any hints would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: it is best to use the code format `{}` at the top of the editor instead of inline ``` code blocks, then you get the correct formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use filter since you are not using data interpolation with `ngBind` directive of `{{}}` tags. In this case you would probably use directive. Very simple one can look like:

```
app.directive('highlight', function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element) {
            scope.$watch('highlightthis', function(newVal, oldVal) {
                if (newVal !== oldVal) {
                   var text = element.text().replace(new RegExp('(' + newVal + ')', 'gi'), '<span class="highlighted">$1</span>');
                    element.html(text); 
                }  
            });
        }
    };
});
```

and used like:

```
<p highlight>some text</p>
<p highlight>some more text</p>
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/Ee9efFhXzDabryH1WBlU?p=preview

Of course it's not very advanced and convenient to use, but you can get the idea of how you can write something like what you need.

**UPD**. Here is more convenient example of hightlight directive:

```
app.directive('highlight', function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            var tags = element[0].querySelectorAll('.highlightable');
            scope.$watch(attr.highlight, function(newVal, oldVal) {
                if (newVal !== oldVal) {
                    angular.forEach(tags, function(tag) {
                        var el = angular.element(tag),
                            text = el.text().replace(new RegExp('(' + newVal + ')', 'gi'), '<span class="highlighted">$1</span>');
                        el.html(text);
                    });

                }  
            });
        }
    };
});
```

which should be used this way:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl" highlight="highlightthis">

    <input ng-model='highlightthis'> {{highlightthis}}

    <p class="highlightable">some text</p>
    <p class="highlightable">some more text</p>
    <p>This content is not highlightable.</p>
    <p>but this is again.</p>

</body>
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/6jG1fXVayZYOVhGCqrjl?p=preview

Comment: if i understand this correctly, both the 'convenient' and 'not convenient' way put a watch on the input model. the first one just searches the whole page for everything and the next one only searches for objects with the specific class set. is that correct?

point is, i'm late loading my pages with a $routeProvider but your solution gave me the right idea.

Comment: i now have this: 
`    $http.get("partials/blogs.json").then(function(ret) {
     $scope.blogs=ret.data;
     $scope.$watch("q", function(newVal, oldVal) { 
      if (newVal !== oldVal) { 
       tags=document.querySelectorAll('.HL');
       angular.forEach(tags, function(tag) { 
        var el = angular.element(tag),
        text = el.text().replace(new RegExp('(' + newVal + ')','gi'), '<span class="highlighted">$1</span>');
        el.html(text);
       });
      } 
     });
`

Comment: not sure if the $watch should be inside the $http or outside of it. i think both should work but i'm unsure which is better for browser resources...